# XML Column Sorting

Tags: xml, sorting, hudson

Hi I am currently doing a verification tool to compare the data precision and integrity of a data generated by the Control-M manually(Called "Baseline") and the data generated by Control-M through Hudson agent (Called "Regresssion").

Below are the codes in the verification-job-sort.xml, and I have it to sort it first between the Baseline and Regression data table.

This one below is the Baseline part. Where the `<constructor-arg value=""/>`
 is where we put the column numbers. I have tried, 0,1,2/etc but its not sorting the data in the table.

```
    <bean id="baseline_file49_sortingTasklet" 
            class="com.hsbc.gbm.grt.bart.regression.verification.springbatch.FlatFileSortingTasklet"> 
            <property name="inputFilePath" value="D:\WR_BART\DRR\Baseline\CDM_DRR_MI_IP_MTM.${Baseline}.csv"/> 
            <property name="tmpDirPath" value="D:\WR_BART\DRR\Baseline\tmp"/> 
            <property name="outputDirPath" value="D:\WR_BART\DRR\Baseline\tmp"/> 
            <property name="linesToSkip" value="0"/> 
            <property name="overwriteIfOutputFileExists" value="true"/> 
            <property name="partitionSizeInMB" value="384"/> 

            <property name="comparator"> 
                    <bean class="com.hsbc.gbm.grt.bart.regression.verification.file.DelimitedLineComparator"> 
                            <constructor-arg value=""/> 
                            <constructor-arg value=","/> 
                    </bean> 
            </property> 
</bean>
```

Then the below one is the regression part. Same as above, I have tried it.

```
    <bean id="regression_file49_sortingTasklet" 
            class="com.hsbc.gbm.grt.bart.regression.verification.springbatch.FlatFileSortingTasklet"> 
            <property name="inputFilePath" value="D:\WR_BART\DRR\Regression\CDM_DRR_MI_IP_MTM.${Regression}.csv"/> 
            <property name="tmpDirPath" value="D:\WR_BART\DRR\Regression\tmp"/> 
            <property name="outputDirPath" value="D:\WR_BART\DRR\Regression\tmp"/> 
            <property name="linesToSkip" value="0"/> 
            <property name="overwriteIfOutputFileExists" value="true"/> 
            <property name="partitionSizeInMB" value="384"/> 

           <property name="comparator"> 
                    <bean class="com.hsbc.gbm.grt.bart.regression.verification.file.DelimitedLineComparator"> 
                            <constructor-arg value=""/> 
                            <constructor-arg value=","/> 
                    </bean> 
            </property> 
</bean>
```

This codes below then came from the file verification-spec.xml which then compare the data between Baseline and Regression after the sorting is done. I have tried adding `<property name="lineOrderingPolicy" value="0,1,"/>` below the `<property name="fieldDelimiter" value="," />`
but still no go.

```
    <bean id="file49_bean"
        class="com.hsbc.gbm.grt.bart.regression.verification.springbatch.item.file.DualCSVFileVerifier"
        parent="outputParentDualCSVFileVerifier">
        <property name="referenceResource" value="CDM_DRR_MI_IP_MTM.${Baseline}_sorted.csv"/>
        <property name="testResource" value="CDM_DRR_MI_IP_MTM.${Regression}_sorted.csv"/>

        <property name="linesToSkip" value="0" />            
        <property name="fieldDelimiter" value="," />

</bean>
```

I have run the verification tool using Hudson, but there are still differences between the files. I have checked the data manually and they are not properly sorted. The verification process works fine, but the sorting does not.

Let me know if I miss to mention something or something you need to know.